# What are some alternatives to multiplication in Java?

Tags: java, hex, masking, bit

To be more specific, there are constraints on my assignment that disallow me to use multiplication and more than 2 if-else statements. The method should take a number, such as 0xAAA5, and replace one of the 4-bit sections with the given nibble, such as 0x1. Here is my code right now:

```
public static int setNibble(int num, int nibble, int which) {
    num = num & (0xFFFF - (0xF << (4 * which)));
    num = num | ( (nibble) << (4 * which) );

    return num;
}
```

I basically just want to left shift by which*4, but I can't figure out how to do that without multiplication, or some kind of if-else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4 * which` == `which << 2`, so you can use that.

Comment: ah, you're correct. so easy I overlooked it :P Thanks!

Comment: Of course, this is subject to overflows ;)

Comment: Any more then `4 * which`?

Comment: No, in fact internally the JVM will eventually do the same -- shifting is faster